# spark cant join dataframes using left outer join

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark

I am trying to join 2 dataframes based on df1.portfolio name to df2.portId
the resulting dataframe  I do not want the same key repeated.

here is my code so far

```
val df = spark.read.json("C:\\json\\portmast") 
val pgetsec = spark.read.json("C:\\json\\pgetsec")


val portfolio_master = df.select("PortfolioCode","Legal Entity Name","Asofdate")
val pgetsecs= pgetsec.select("TransId", "SecId","portId","GaapCurBkBal","ParBal","SetlDt","SetlPric","OrgBkBal","TradeDt","StatCurBkBal","NaicRtg","SecurityTypeCode","CamraSecType","FundType","CountryIso")
val pg = portfolio_master.join(pgetsec,Seq("PortfolioCode","portId"),"left_outer")
```

the error I am getting is
 `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: using columns ['PortfolioCode,'portId] can not be resolved given input columns:`

 Final json should look like this

```
|-- Portfolio Code: string (nullable = true)
|-- Legal Entity Name: string (nullable = true)
|-- Asofdate: string (nullable = true)

((SI, S&P 500 Index,9/30/2016),[0.0,Equity,Common Stock])
((SI, S&P 500 Index,9/30/2016),[0.0,Equity,Common Stock])
((SI, S&P 500 Index,9/30/2016),[0.0,Equity,Common Stock])
[SI1, S&P 500 Index,9/30/2016,CompactBuffer([0.0,Equity,Common     Stock],    [0.0,Equity,Common Stock], [0.0,Equity,Common Stock])]
root
|-- Portfolio Code: string (nullable = true)
|-- Legal Entity Name: string (nullable = true)
|-- Asofdate: string (nullable = true)
|-- Security: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- BondPrice: double (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- CoreSectorLevel1Code: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- CoreSectorLevel2Code: string (nullable = true)

+--------------+-------------------+---------+--------------------+
|Portfolio Code|  Legal Entity Name| Asofdate|            Security|
+--------------+-------------------+---------+--------------------+
|           SI | S&P 500 Index     |9/30/2016|[[0.0,Equity,Comm...|
+--------------+-------------------+---------+--------------------+
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The columns that you are trying to join on don't exist in the second DataFrame ?

Comment: both are Json files I am reading in file 1 it is called portfolioCode and in second  Json file it is called  portId.  the data behind the keys  is same  I want  do  something like this   select p.portfoliocode, ..., ps.secid,ps.Transid,.... from portfolio_master p left join  pgetsec ps on p.portfoliocode = ps.portid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`portId` doesn't exist in `portfolio_master` and `PortfolioCode` doesn't exist in `pgetsec`.  If you reread the full error message you'll see it explains this as it also shows the available columns.

What you want is `portfolio_master("PortfolioCode") === pgetsec("portId")` as your join condition.

Comment: I  want to create the resulting json to not  repeat the key information for  every record  so it looks something like this

Comment: Then you can either drop one of the key columns after the join or rename them before the join so that they are the same and do the join like you were before.

Comment: updating question to show final json schema and how  should see the data